# Notation of functions

Tags: functions, notation

For example, we have a definition of a cryptosystem:

We define a cryptosystem as tuple $\langle M, K, C\rangle$ where $M$ is a set of texts that are not ciphered, $K$ set of keys, $C$ set of texts that are ciphered. We also define two operations 
$$ e(\cdot|K_e) :M\rightarrow C$$
$$ d(\cdot|K_d): C \rightarrow M$$
Where
$$\langle K_e, K_d\rangle \in K\ \mbox{such that}\ d(e(M|K_e)|K_d)=M$$

Well, definition is irrelevant, what I am interested is notation used to define functions, I haven't seen it before. How do I need to interpret the part in parenthesis $(\cdot|K_e)$? Is it simply a two-argument function? Does the dot signify anything besides "here goes an argument from a set $M$"?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the $\cdot$ allows you to consider it as a one variable function, as an example let $f(x,y):\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ now 
$$f(\cdot,y):\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$$
$$f(x,\cdot):\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$$

To give an example of how this can be useful, lets consider the map $B:H\times H\to \mathbb R$ (the spaces are irrelevant), but $B$ is a Bilinear form if both 
$$B(\cdot,v):H\to\mathbb R$$ and
$$B(u,\cdot):H\to\mathbb R$$ are linear maps.

Sadly I don't know much about cryptography, but generally $|$ is a mathematical notion for "given", i.e. $P(A|B)$ is the probablility of $A$ given $ B$ has happened.

In this case we have $e(⋅|K_e):M→C$, so it seems that the input is irrelevant, because you already have enough information (this is just my guess of what this means)

Comment: Could you please explain more about this? Why would anyone need to do this? Perhaps you could provide a link to some reference? Also, could you explain the usage of "|" symbol in definition? What does it signify? Or is it interchangeable with ","?

Comment: @user1242967 I have edited to provide some more information, hopefully it helps.